# Get id of .class from php do-while loop

Tags: php, jquery

```
do{
<div class="fine" id="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $tb_dt_01 ?></div>
}while..........

$($('.fine').attr('id')).mouseover(function() {
alert($('.fine').attr('id'));
});
```

I have the above do-while php loop, the results are displayed with $i incremental.  I want to get the id from .fine.  But currently it gives me the first value or no value. The alert is just given as a test, to check if the values are given correctly

Comment: this would result in syntax error..

Comment: If I'm right, do{}while{} is php...

Comment: @genesis thats what the title says, anyway the issue is resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$(".fine").mouseover(function() {
  alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```